# How can I split a pandas string column at the last instance of an integer?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex

I have a pandas dataset which contains a string column. The cell values consist of letters and number, for ex- `'AB3 AB5 String'`. I want to split it in 2 columns at the last instance of a number in the string. Basically-> `'AB3 AB5'` and `'String'`. Another example would be to split `'CD4 String Text'` to `'CD4'` and `'String Text'`.

I have tried using

```
df['New Column'] = df['Orignal Column'].str.split(pat='\d', n= -1).str[2]
```

This gives me the latter half of the desired result (i.e `'String'` in our example) but not the first half (i.e. `'AB3 AB5'`), since the above code splits at every instance of a number and I am picking the 3rd element of the list so created, which does half the job. I have tried using variations of the above code to get the first half but not getting the desired output.

Comment: Maybe `df[['New Column1', 'New Column2']] = df['Orignal Column'].str.extract(r'(.*\d)\s*(.*)')`?

Comment: Or do you just want to extract all text after last digit only? Like `df['New Column'] = df['Orignal Column'].str.extract(r'([^\d\s]\D*)$', expand=False)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the latter string, don't `split` but rather [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with an end-of-string anchor (`$`). Splitting is more expensive, and you also need to slice afterwards.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['AB3 AB5 String', 'CD4 String Text']})

df['new'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'([^\d]+)$', expand=False)
```

If you must have a number, else you don't want to match:

```
df['new2'] = df['col'].str.extract(r'\d\s*([^\d]+)$', expand=False)
```

Output:

```
               col           new          new2
0   AB3 AB5 String        String        String
1  CD4 String Text   String Text   String Text
2        only text     only text           NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution similar to mozway's but with a few different tweaks:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
       'Original Column': ["AB3 AB5 String", "CD4 String Text", "String Text", "AB3", ""] 
    }
)

columns_extracted = df['Original Column'].str.extract(r"^(?P<First_part>.*\d+)?(?P<Second_part>[^\d]*)$")

final_df = pd.concat([df, columns_extracted], axis=1)

print(final_df)
```

I will let you decide which solution you prefer.